# How to iterate over all columns using pandas and save output to file

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I want to iterate over all of the columns in my dataset and discover if a column contains a one or a zero.

My dataset is a matrix of 68x300000.

I am reading the file using pandas:

```
df= pd.read_csv("filepath", header=None)
```

From this output I want to create a new matrix of 1x300000 detailing which column is a one or a zero.

Is there a function which will allow me to do this? Which is the most efficient method?

Comment: `df.isin([0, 1]).any(axis=0)`?

Comment: @jezrael, comments are not to accuse posters of plagiarism. Please flag to a moderator if you believe this is the case. Associated meta: [How should I deal with claims that my answer is plagiarism of another?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364058/how-should-i-deal-with-claims-that-my-answer-is-plagiarism-of-another)

Comment: Can you explain more, what you need? array with `0 and 1` if exist `0,1` in columns?

Comment: I need to know if any of the columns contain anything other than 0. I need the output to display for each column either a 0 or 1 depending on whether the column contains a zero or other figure.

Comment: @B.Allen - are data numeric? what return `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @B.Allen, how does my solution look? Can you tell us *exactly* how the output should look. What happens if 0 and 1 both exist in a column?

Comment: @jezrael it returns: int64, dtype: object

Comment: @jpp your solution compiles but does not return anything, when I print the variable it just returns the column number. If there is a 0 and a 1 in a column, a 1 should be returned

Comment: OK, I'm afraid I can't help further. My solution works "as-is" since it includes input, logic and output. Any difference can only be due to your data being different.

Comment: @B.Allen - If my solution does not work, then some data problem. Od do you think only `0 and `1` in some column?

Comment: @jpp as my data has 300000 columns I can't really specify `Index(['A', 'B']` like you have in your example. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @B.Allen, my example does not specify `Index(['A', 'B']`. This is the *output* or result. If it's a long list, you are not obligated to print it.

Comment: @B.Allen - I modify answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:list('abcdef'),
                   1:[4,1,4,5,5,4],
                   2:[7,0,9,4,2,3],
                   3:[1,0,1,0,1,0],
                   4:[5,3,6,0,2,4],
                   5:list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  1  0  0  3  a
2  c  4  9  1  6  a
3  d  5  4  0  0  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

If want check if for some columns are `0` and `1` values only:

```
b = ((df.values == 0) | (df.values == 1)).all(axis=0).astype(int)
print (b)
[0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

If want check if for some columns are `0` and `1` values at least once:

```
c = ((df.values == 0) | (df.values == 1)).any(axis=0).astype(int)
print (c)
[0 1 1 1 1 0]

c = df.isin([0, 1]).any().astype(int)
print (c)
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    0
dtype: int32
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(456) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(68,300000)))
#print (df)

In [272]: %timeit df.columns[df.isin([0, 1]).any()]
1 loop, best of 3: 323 ms per loop

In [273]: %timeit df.columns.values[((df.values == 0) | (df.values == 1)).any(axis=0)]
10 loops, best of 3: 48.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `numpy` for this. Below is an example.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                   [0, 1, 5],
                   [8, 9, 10]],
                 columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

a = df.values    

result = df.columns[((a == 0) | (a == 1)).any(axis=0)]

Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

The below may suffice for your updated requirements. It deals also with instances where 0 *and* 1 are included in a column.

```
res = {col: {k: (a[:, i] == k).any() for k in (0, 1)} for i, col in enumerate(df)}

{'A': {0: True, 1: True}, 'B': {0: False, 1: True}, 'C': {0: False, 1: False}}
```